# How to find the mode of an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, statistics, mode

How would you find the mode of an ArrayList in Java?#

```
  public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> max = new <Integer> ();
    //* declared arrayList and gets values 




    #how do I calculate the mode of the arrayList?#
```

Comment: what do you mean by mode ?

Comment: I think probabilities mode...

Comment: In statistics, the functions mean, median, and mode.  Mode being the most frequently occurring term in the given arrayList.

Comment: Create a HashMap and count the ocurrences of each number?

Comment: Has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387786/finding-modes-an-an-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141723/javahow-do-i-find-the-mode-most-frequent-value-in-an-array-using-a-simple-fo